# Get all children of a term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I  have the following tree structure, I want to get all child terms. I implemented `taxonomy_get_children('tid')` drupal api function.

```
1.Gloves
 1.1 Seamless
   1.1.1 Kevlar
    1.1.1.1 Shell
    1.1.1.2 Dots
    1.1.1.3 Coated
 1.2 mechanics
 1.3 cut and sewn
2.Apparels
 2.1 Coveralls
 2.2 Aprons
 2.3 Trousers
```

When I clicked on `Apparels` I successsfully get all child terms using but when I clicked on `Gloves`, it provides me only top level child terms `('seamless', 'mechanics','cut and sewn')`, not the deep levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `taxonomy_get_tree` instead, it takes vocabulary ID as the first param, and the term ID under which to generate the tree - this should give you all children of a term.

More info [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7).